# there is a plethora of investigations which indicate/indicates

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses, quantifiers

"There is a plethora of investigations which indicate how it works...."
or
"There is a plethora of investigations which indicates how it works.."

Does the verb "to indicate" refer to the plethora or investigations?

Comment: ...which indicate/s what? It could be the investigations that indicate something, or it could be the sheer number of investigations that is the significant factor here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k it does not matter what they indicate... but I wonder whether it should be indicate or indicates?

Comment: As I said, it depends on who/what is doing the indicating. We don't have enough context to determine that.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the investigations indicate sth as sth.... for instance

Comment: If you're sure it's the investigations, then of course you want to use *indicate*, because *investigations* is plural.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Does it work  in this instance " There is a large number of theories which present..." ? right?

Comment: *There is a basket of flowers that smell good* / *There is a basket of flowers that smells good.*  I'd guess here that the flowers smell good, not the basket.  Does the *plethora* indicate how it works, or do the investigations?  I'd guess here that the investigations indicate how it works, not the plethora.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime - could you make that an answer, please?

Comment: @aparente001 certainly, done.