# The plethora of environmental issues are rising or a plethora of environmental issues is rising?

Tags: grammar, american-english, syntactic-analysis

"The plethora of environmental issues are rising at alarming rate due to exploitation of nature by human kind."
Is this sentence grammatically right? I am confused if this sentence is right or I should write as "A plethora of environmental issues is rising at alarming rate due to exploitation of nature by human kind." 
I am writing this sentence as general statement to begin the essay.

Comment: Similar: [there is a plethora of investigations which indicate/indicates](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390328), [“There is a plethora…” or “There are a plethora…”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103176)

Comment: If you could first list all the reasonable choices then explain your own preference, that might be a reasonable Question. Until then, IMHO, it remains a matter of stylistic choice, which is far better suited to some kind of writers' forum than here.